# is there a possibility to make some lines in image in python with turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

i am trying to make some lines or draw somthing in GIF image in python with turtle but the line show before the picture .please help this is my code

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.getscreen()
t1 = turtle.Turtle()

screen.addshape('white.gif')
```

t1.shape('white.gif')
t1.fd(100)
t1.rt(90)

turtle.done()

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to draw on an image, you can make the image the background, and then use the turtle to draw onto it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

screen.bgpic("white.gif")

turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```